# Talk to javascript with c# and vice versa

Tags: c#, javascript, tcp, websocket

I am creating a website where I need to have access to the clients files. I know that the client will have to accept some warning message and also run my progam.

I have reaserched on the internet and I know that I can acomplish this with Web Sockets. I have been able to establish a tcp connection localy from c# and google chrom html 5 websocket. the problem with websockets is that it did not work with other browsers.

Another solution that I was thinking was to use cookies to exchange messages. I havent tried that and I dont think that will be efficient.

Some websites when giving them privilades are able to use java. I have no idea how they exchange messages but maybe there is a similar way of doing it with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at SignalR -- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR.  Be careful though, web sockets (and any other "per user" type connection has server resource implications -- see http://robrich.org/archive/2012/04/05/The-real-time-web-in-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx